# How to integrate a partial fraction problem of the form $\frac{(ax+b)}{(ax^2 + bx + c)^n}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, intuition, partial-fractions

Please help me integrating a partial fraction problem of the form $$\frac{(ax+b)}{(ax^2 + bx + c)^n}$$

My professor gave this explanation which loses me at $Step-2$.

[image]

Can anyone explain this to me in plain English? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What's in the title (which should actually be in the body, too) is already in partial fraction form. No further reduction is necessary.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, could you expand on your comment? It seems many more steps happen after Step 2. I'm most confused on the transition from 1 to 2

Comment: I don't follow links that lead offsite. Please write out, in the body of your post, the math that needs explanation. There is help available on how to format mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

So this given solution has a lot of things going on. Hopefully the following will give some clarity.

We want to integrate $\frac{Ax + B}{(ax^2 + bx + c)^n}$ with $b^2 - 4ac < 0$. We first simplify our calculations by factoring out $a^n$ to get $\frac{A'x + B'}{(x^2 + \frac{b}{a}x + \frac{c}{a})^n}$ where $A' = A / a^n$ and $B' = B/a^n$. Now we can complete the square as follows:
$$x^2 + (b/a)x + (c/a) = \left(x + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 + \frac{c}{a} - \frac{b^2}{4a^2}.$$ Since $b^2 - 4ac < 0$ we have $$\frac{c}{a} - \frac{b^2}{4a^2} = \frac{1}{4a^2}(4ac - b^2) > 0.$$ Now let $r^2 =  \frac{c}{a} - \frac{b^2}{4a^2}$ and $rt = x + b/2a$ so $dx = r dt$. Now our integral becomes $$\int \frac{A'x + B'}{(x^2 + \frac{b}{a}x + \frac{c}{a})^n}dx = \int\frac{A'(rt - b/2a) + B'}{((rt)^2 + r^2)^n}rdt = \int \frac{(A'r^2/r^{2n})t + (B'r - rb/2a)/r^{2n}}{(t^2 +1)^n}dt = \int\frac{Ct + D}{(t^2 + 1)}dt$$ where $C = A'r^2/r^{2n}$ and $D = (B'r - rb/2a)/r^{2n}$.

Let me know if you need to clarify anything further or explain the rest of the solution.